# How to bind odata based on the login user

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

How can we bind an O DATA based on signed in user, need to provide information user specific. how its is working..

I am beginner in SAP UI 5, Please help

Answer (score 2):

If you are exposing *CDS* as *oData*, you can use the session variables. `$session.user` variable one of them.

If you are manipulating data in ABAP class you can use `SY-UNAME` variable.